# React Plugin Architecture with dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dynamic, plugins

I want to build a SPA on the client site, which supports a plugin concept.
You should be able to copy a package inside a specific folder and the server should load this component after a restart. This plugin should work without any information stored inside the base program.

I need to dynamically load a component by name. I do not have a map of all possible components. How can I load a component by only knowing its name?

Answer (score -1):

you can check out `React.lazy`. This helps with dynamic loading components which you want, but with this you need to wrap it to Suspense, because component will load not immediately.

> ```js
> // This component is loaded dynamically
> const SomeComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./SomeComponent'));
> <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}><SomeComponent/></Suspense>
> ```

Comment: Hi, please don't post link-only answers. **1.** links can expire rendering your post absolutely useless. **2.** you force users to leave this site to get more information. Links are fine as a supplement: try quoting a relevant portion. (I understand that the question hasn't given you much to go off of, being so broad. So I don't blame you!) See the edits I made.